# How do I make a plot on markdown not move?

Tags: image, grid, rstudio, markdown, move

I'm trying to write a paper on markdown and I have some tables before the images that I included which used the "hold_position" parameter to make them not move around. I'm wondering if I can do the same thing with my images. I've included this code:

```
  {r setup, include=FALSE}
  #making images don't move positions
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos= "h")
```

Which makes my imported images move such as: `![fig](fig.png)` not move around.

However, the image I made with plot_grid still moves around:

```
plot_grid(ch2014,ch2015,ch2016,ch2017,ch2018, align = "v", nrow = 3, rel_heights = c(120, 120, 90, 90, 120))
```

Is there any method like a "hold_position" to not make the images move?

Edit: I solved the issue by using \clearpage which has the same effects as \newpage but does not account for any floats

Answer (score 0):

From a previous comment I found online:

Floating figures and tables can move past \newpage, so what is happening is that the \newpage does start a new page, then inserts the figure, then starts the references section.

You want \clearpage, which has the same effect as \newpage but restricts floats as well. If there are pending floats when \clearpage hits, a float page is created only after which the content will continue.